# Prevent Http access to api

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, https

Is it possible to prevent requests that are not using https from calling a get/post in code.

For example I am implementing a rest api with **java** and **spring**, and I would like to return a http status to the caller if they were not using https.

`/api/getBlah` using https would return the item, however using just http would not work and return the appropriate http status.

Comment: i would add a redirect with an webserver (apache, nginx) from http to https, solves the problem

Comment: @DZDomi is right, this kind of issue is usually solved by properly configuring the server to not allow access to resources over http.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an API server, I strongly encourage you to **don't answer a redirect**

If you do answer a redirect, if a developer make the mistake to use the http version of your API he will not see immediately that he used an insecure connexion

If you answer a "400 Bad Request", "401 Unauthorized" or a "405 Method Not Allowed" with a body explaining that only https is allowed, then the developer will immediately see the problem.

In short, **answering a redirect http=>https in an API encourage bad practices**.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Tom, Do you have any idea how I could detect if the call came from a http or https in spring java? Then I could return the Http Status when using http

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#isSecure() no ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways of handling this.  **Web Server Handling** in my opinion, is the most common and makes the best use of the strengths of web servers and application serves.

**Web Server Handling**

As mentioned in the comments above, a common method of deploying Java web applications is to place a web server (such as apache or nginx) in front of a Java Application Server (tomcat, wildfly, jetty, etc.).  The web server then proxies requests to the application server.

In a setup like this you can simply return a static response or redirect the user..  In this way, you don't need to return anything special from your own Java application.  The web server does the lifting for you.

It should be noted (as in the answer from @Tom), that in the API use-case, an HTTP to HTTPS redirect is not best approach.  This is more commonly

**Application Server Separate Servlets**

On the Java side, you could essentially create two separate web applications.  The first would be configured to receive requests from the HTTP listener and would provide proper error messages or redirects.  The other would be your main application and would be configured to only receive requests from the HTTPS listener.

Again responding with a static error would be best for an API.

**Application Server Single Application**

When a servlet handles requests, it will populate information in the ServletRequest, including information about if the requests was secure (used HTTPS).  See the [ServletRequest documentation][2] and specifically the `isSecure()` method.  You can inspect the ServletReuest within your application to determine the appropriate way of responding to the request.

**Don't Answer**
You can also simply configure your webserver/app server to not listen for HTTP requests.  You'll miss the change to provide a sensible error to the user, but you'll achieve the affect of not allowing any requests over HTTP.

Comment: Answering a redirect http=>https in an API encourage bad practices and hide mistakes. Furthermore, if the api request contains confidential information, it allow lazy developers to not protect them as they should.

Comment: Fair point, usually you see HTTP->HTTPS redirects at a web site level, enforcing that no pages are served, and users always interact with the server.  But agreed, this is not the same for an API.  The approaches remain the same however, I'll adjust the answer.

Comment: Yes. HTTP=>HTTPS makes sense in a browser context because the use can see the presence or absence of http in the end (and HSTS apply), but for API requests, once the code is written and working, no one will check it again, and most of the time HSTS will not apply...